# Reassign index of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
Month
1    -0.075844
2    -0.089111
3     0.042705
4     0.002147
5    -0.010528
6     0.109443
7     0.198334
8     0.209830
9     0.075139
10   -0.062405
11   -0.211774
12   -0.109167
1    -0.075844
2    -0.089111
3     0.042705
4     0.002147
5    -0.010528
6     0.109443
7     0.198334
8     0.209830
9     0.075139
10   -0.062405
11   -0.211774
12   -0.109167
Name: Passengers, dtype: float64
```

As you can see numbers are listed twice from 1-12 / 1-12, instead, I would like to change the index to 1-24. The problem is that when plotting it I see the following:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(esta2,color='orange')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

I would like to see a continuous line from 1 to 24.

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`esta2 = esta2.reset_index()` will get you 0-23. If you need 1-24 then you could just do `esta2.index = np.arange(1, len(esta2) + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

quite simply :

```
df.index = [i for i in range(1,len(df.index)+1)]
df.index.name = 'Month'
```

---

```
print(df)
           Val
Month          
1     -0.075844
2     -0.089111
3      0.042705
4      0.002147
5     -0.010528
6      0.109443
7      0.198334
8      0.209830
9      0.075139
10    -0.062405
11    -0.211774
12    -0.109167
13    -0.075844
14    -0.089111
15     0.042705
16     0.002147
17    -0.010528
18     0.109443
19     0.198334
20     0.209830
21     0.075139
22    -0.062405
23    -0.211774
24    -0.109167
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reassign the index:

```
df.index = pd.Index(range(1, len(df) + 1), name='Month')
```